# How To Detect User Exact City Location?

Tags: vb.net, ip, detection, city

I am developing dummy laptop locator generator. I would like to know if there is any way to detect user's precise city based on their home IP?

I thought I would use maxmind.com API but it sometimes doesn't detect city right. For my home IP it detected right but for my VPS it didn't. I really need some solution to detect city 100% right and if possible street with GPS coordinates. Is it possible?

Comment: Is there any other way to detect right city? I am going to install application on their PC. If they give me privileges is there a way to find it?

Comment: Simply, you can't. For example my ISP isnt' close to where I'm located, but it show's that I'm listed about 4 hours away...

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to determine someone's location by their IP address alone with any reasonable reliability.